# How to sum values ​within a list using the scripted field in Kibana

Tags: kibana, opensearch, scriptedfield

I'm trying to add these values ​​of the "gapsLength" result but I still haven't had success, can anyone help

the image below shows the list I'm talking about

[Gap Average result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeXHO.png)

I tried something like this

```
int sum = 0;
for (int number : doc["gap average.gapsLength"]) {
    sum += number;
}
return sum;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your code is almost there, it may be lacking just some `painless` syntax improvements. Example:

```
for (int number in doc['gap average.gapsLength']) {
   ...
}
```